# Node.js server won't start on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems I have something very wrong with my set up, I currently have `node -v //v0.10.29` installed on my windows 7 64Bit machine.

```
// Include http module.
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.on("end", function () {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        response.end('Hello HTTP!');
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

This is the file I have running via `node http.js`. There is nothing else in the folder other than this file.

Running this little badboy: `node-inspector & node --debug http.js` the following is returned in the cmd:

```
Node Inspector v0.7.4
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

I can navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and also the suggested url, navigating with `debug?etc` gives me a console, similar to chrome's developers tools.

Navigating to the url without the params gives me `Cannot GET /` with the request `404`'in

With said headers:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1:8080
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like  Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 17 Jul 2014 23:07:13 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express
```

So how can i connect to a simple http server in `node.js` and `windows 7`

Comment: I believe the file I am sending is `node http.js` or `http.js`, no?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Include http module.
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.on("end", function () {
        // ...
    }); 
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen(8080);
```

To understand the problem, we can do some experiments.

Add console logs around responses and request end event

```
console.log("response start");
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end('Hello World\n');
console.log("response end");
request.on("end", function () {
    console.log("request end");
});
```

The output:

```
   response start
   response end
   request end
```

Then comment out this line of response.end.

```
console.log("response start");
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
//response.end('Hello World\n');
console.log("response end");
request.on("end", function () {
    console.log("request end");
});
```

Now the request is stuck. The end event is never emitted.

```
response start
response end
```

So the conclusion is end event of request only be fired after response.end is done. You **shouldn't place your response in the body of request's end event**.

Comment: This doesn't change anything from the OP's code except add a syntax error.

Comment: Much improved answer!